# Mysql WorkBench : Exporting table data backup?

Tags: export, mysql-workbench

How do I export tabluar data using Mysql WorkBench 5.2.37 CE Rev 8576? It seems I can export table schemas no problem but the .sql file generated has no data whatsoever?

Steps taken:

1. Established and Connected to Database
2. Go To Manage Import / Export
3. Go To Data Export
4. Select Databases and Tables
5. Export to Dump Project Folder
6. Start Export

Is it that this program won't export data?
Am I doing something wrong?
Is it a bug?

Comment: via CLI: `mysqldump -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] > dumpfilename.sql` [src0](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump/#more-184) [src1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3031414/495132)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The export should be default include the table data. Make sure that **Skip table data (no-data)** in the options sub-panel is unchecked before you start the export.

If that doesn't work, try reverse engineering your database by going to the menu option **Database > Reverse Engineer** and complete the steps.

After you've reverse engineered your database, go to **File > Export > Forward Engineer SQL CREATE Script**.

Under **SQL Options**, check the box **Generate INSERT statements for Tables** and then continue the export process.

Comment: Yes that worked, I didn't see that option earlier lol... Is there a way to make this automatically reoccurring in the windows task manager like in the old MYSQL Administration software before Workbench?